# Spring Boot Application Deployment issue on Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic, thymeleaf

I have a Spring boot application that uses Thymeleaf as a template engine, I added a default controller that should redirects to Home page when deploying on server, Controller code snippet below:

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController
{
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index()
    {
       return "index";
    }
}
```

The index is resolved by ViewResolver to the matching web page.

When deploying the generated war "**app.war**" on a standalone Tomcat instance, the application works just fine and I am being redirected to the Home page (**localhost:XXX/context_path/index**), "**localhost:XXX/<context_path>**" also redirects to the correct page.

When deploying on Weblogic, I get an error when I try to access the URL:
"**localhost:XXX/context_path**" and it works when I manually add "**/**".

I found this tutorial https://o7planning.org/en/11245/deploying-spring-mvc-on-oracle-weblogic-server that suggests adding / to weblogic.xml file which works just fine.

However, when forcing the context-root to "**/**", the home page URL for the application deployed on weblogic is no longer the same
("**localhost:XXX/index**" instead of "**localhost:XXX/war_name/index**").

To sum up, Tomcat adds automatically the "**/**" to the context root without configuring a context-root.

How can I get the same behaviour with weblogic without having to configure context-root on weblogic.xml?

I am using a weblogic Server 12c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I anyone is still having the same issue, The solution was to perform a simple hack on the static file being served by Spring, the default index file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.location.pathname.slice(-1) !== '/') {
    window.location.assign(window.location.pathname + '/');
  }
</script>
```